# Internal server error using apache2 and google-cloud-storage

Tags: flask, apache2, google-cloud-storage, digital-ocean

So i managed to getting everything hooked up.The path for google and setting up apache2 seems to be running well .However i'm getting an internal error ;/ within the server.In the function hello

`storage_client= storage.Client()` results in an error

within the function test

`storage_client= storage.Client()`
results in success and python was able to find the secret.json
which is strange to me..

```
#__init__.py code
from flask import Flask
from google.cloud import storage

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    #Does not work here
    storage_client= storage.Client()
    return "error"

#Works without @app.route("")
def test():    
    storage_client= storage.Client()
    # successfuly connects and prints
    print(storage_client) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

```
#wsgi code
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/usr/secret.json
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/html/FlaskApp/")
from google.cloud import storage
from FlaskApp import app as application

application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

Here are the logs it seems like there is an error in flaskapp.wsgi but i'm not too sure...

```
mod_wsgi (pid=23303): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.


mod_wsgi (pid=23303): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/html/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
from FlaskApp import app as application
File "/var/www/html/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
 storage_client = storage.Client()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/


raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
 DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or ex$
```

Comment: Is the VM be on premise or on GCP?

Comment: no ;/ @guillaumeblaquiere

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the **credentials** for the service account you're planning to use. As you can see in the error, you can set the [environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable) **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** for that.

To achieve that, complete the following steps:

- Download the [**service account key**](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#iam-service-account-keys-create-console) in JSON format for the service account you're planning to use.
- (on **Linux** or **MacOS**) run: 
  `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH-TO-THE-KEY]"`
- (on **Windows**): `$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH-TO-THE-KEY]"`

---

**Alternatively**, you can [pass the path](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_the_path_to_the_service_account_key_in_code) to the service account key in your code:

```
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
        'service_account_key.json')
```